# Is there a way to make macros show up in Visual Studio's Intellisense context menu?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, macros, intellisense, function-prototypes

Suppose that I have the following function prototype:

```
#define WHATEVER
void MyFunction(WHATEVER int &x);
```

Such that I can use `WHATEVER` to label the parameters of the functions for documentation purposes. Is there a way to make `WHATEVER` show up in the Visual Studio's Intellisense context-menu that shows the functions prototypes when we start typing the name of a function?

Comment: There's another way to document a functions arguments, and that's called *documentation*. In Visual Studio you can add special [XML-based comments](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177226.aspx) as documentation, and the IDE will parse it and give you proper IntelliSense popups.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Many thanks, that was helpful. I am just beginning to use VS and didn't realize that. It will be very useful. In any case, I would be still interested in learning whether there is a way to make macros appear inside function prototypes in VS Intellisense context menu.

Comment: @RSch, do you want to develop a VS extension to implement your requirement? If so, you can think about add tag: visual-studio-extension to get a more professional support for the development issue.